# How to validate each xml tag against xsd and write the tags that pass validation to a new xml file

Tags: xml, xsd

I have two files one is xml and another is xsd, now I want to validate the xml file against the xsd schema by going through each tag and eventually,rewriting the tags that pass the validation test to a new xml file.

```
<?php

    function libxml_display_error($error)
    {
    $return = "<br/>\n";
    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "<b>Warning $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "<b>Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "<b>Fatal Error $error->code</b>: ";
            break;
    }
    $return .= trim($error->message);
    if ($error->file) {
        $return .=    " in <b>$error->file</b>";
    }
    $return .= " on line <b>$error->line</b>\n";

    return $return;
}

function libxml_display_errors() {
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        print libxml_display_error($error);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

// Enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('example.xml');

if (!$xml->schemaValidate('example.xsd')) {
    print '<b>DOMDocument::schemaValidate() Generated Errors!</b>';
    libxml_display_errors();
}else{
     var_dump($xml);
}
```

The above code output only if the entire xml file is valid, is there a way to validate elements like, if some elements pass the validation test then we re-write the valid elements to another xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "tags" you mean "elements", you can do this in XSLT 3.0 using logic such as the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:try>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." validation="lax">
    <xsl:catch errors="*"/>
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:template>
```

This will copy the entire subtree of an element that passes validation to the output; perhaps you only wanted to output the element name. If that's the case you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>    
  <xsl:try>   
    <xsl:variable name="copy" as="element(*)">      
      <xsl:copy-of select="." validation="lax">
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="name($copy)"/>
    <xsl:catch errors="*"/>
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I forgot to be more specific, this is supposed to be done in php. There are some php functions that can validate the entire xml file, but I want to validate elements in the file.

Comment: I've added a PHP tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay